# youtube-dl: Optimum settings for speech quality - podcasts or audiobooks

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, youtube

There is a huge YouTube playlist containing speeches. I wish to convert them all into the [best audio format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)#Quality_comparison_and_low-latency_performance) OPUS with minimum file size. For speech audio tracks [they recommend](https://wiki.xiph.org/Opus_Recommended_Settings#Recommended_Bitrates) a Bitrate of 24 (mono) or 32 (stereo) kbps.

`youtube-dl` offers the option `--audio-quality [1-9]`, where 9 should produce the smallest audio file. But with this setting it produced a OPUS file with variable bitrate around 100 kbps, instead of those mentioned above.

This is how I tried it:

```
youtube-dl -f bestaudio --max-downloads 99 --extract-audio \
   --audio-format opus --audio-quality 8 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" PLAYLIST-URL
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the man pages explanation for `--audio-quality`:

```
--audio-quality QUALITY
          Specify ffmpeg/avconv audio quality, insert a value between 0 
          (better) and 9 (worse) for VBR or a specific bitrate like 128K (default 5)
```

You have to include a unit on the number if you want it to be fixed, otherwise it defaults to VBR.

So try this instead:

```
$ youtube-dl -f bestaudio --max-downloads 99 --extract-audio \
   --audio-format opus --audio-quality 100K -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" PLAYLIST-URL
```

#### References

- [Can't use YouTube-dl to download specified bitrate [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930699/cant-use-youtube-dl-to-download-specified-bitrate)

Comment: I did read this already. But it does not tell me, which average VBR it will be, if I set 9 for variable bitrate.

Comment: @gloschtla - directs to the source that shows audio-quality - https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/487.